# How to deactivate region in AWS through the CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to deactivate an accounts regions via the CLI is it possible to do through the CLI?

I can do it via the AWS console IAM -> Account Settings -> Region -> Deactivate

Answer (score 1):

According to [AWS: Allows Enabling and Disabling AWS Regions - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_aws-enable-disable-regions.html), the IAM permissions related to enabling accounts is prefixed by `account:`:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "EnableDisableHongKong",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "account:EnableRegion",
                "account:DisableRegion"
            ],
            "Resource": "",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {"account:TargetRegion": "ap-east-1"}
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "ViewConsole",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "aws-portal:ViewAccount",
                "account:ListRegions"
            ],
            "Resource": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

I **could not find any AWS CLI commands** for the `account` category. (Nor did I see any in boto3.)

I *did* manage to find a reference of the actions at: [Actions, Resources, and Condition Keys for AWS Accounts - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_awsaccounts.html). So, it might just be a matter of time until it appears in the various SDKs and the AWS CLI.

This answer was written in June 2019, so things might have changed later.

Comment: OK I guess I didnt miss something in the AWS CLI, thanks.